# 1000+ ETH address with a single wallet & transfer all USDC to a single account

Tags: wallets, wallet-transfer

This is what im trying to achieve with little success:

1:) Create 1000+ eth address that belong to a single seed!

( Did this using Mnemonic Code Converter but in ledger i have to use the Derivation index to use them individually. This is a logistical nightmare. )

2:) Manage these wallets or send the USDC from all the wallets to a single address.

3:) Have a primary account or a single address pay for the fees. ( than having eth in all accounts )

*I'm a developer but not a solidity developer. Would love some direction!*

Comment: There is an blog post from coinbase https://blog.coinbase.com/usdc-payment-processing-in-coinbase-commerce-b1af1c82fb0 where they explain how they used smart contracts to manage payments at scale.

Comment: Thanks for that. Ill take a look!